# How to remove javascript property to a <a> tag and replace it with other jQuery properties?

Tags: jquery

I found this code in codepen.io simply simple, I really do not have any error in the code works perfectly.

I would like to be able to remove the javascript attributes in the  tag and be able to add another type of control to continue or back the steps of the form.

Then remove this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="show_step('1')">back</a>
<a href="#" onclick="show_step('3')">next</a>
```

And replace with a control in this way:

```
<a href="#back" class="btn btn-warning back">back</a>
<a href="#next" class="btn btn-success next">next</a>
```

And thus eliminate these attributes that are easy to modify from the browser console.

`onclick="show_step('1')"`

```js
let currentStep = 1; // Variable that indicates the current step

function show_step(step) {
  var data = $("#form").serialize();
  var url = 'saveTemp.php?step=' + step;
  var valid = true;

  // [OPTIONAL] We validate only if it is going forward
  if (currentStep < step) {
  
    // We search all input fields within the current step.  
    $('#step' + currentStep).find('input').each((idx, el) => {
      $field = $(el);

      // If the field is empty
      if (!$field.val()) {
        $field.parent().addClass('error');
        valid = false;
      } else {
        $field.parent().removeClass('error');
      }
    });
  }

  // If at least one field was not completed
  if (!valid) {
    return;
  }

  $('#step' + currentStep).css("display", "none");
  $('#step' + step).fadeIn("slow");
  currentStep = step;
};

$(function() {
  $('#step' + currentStep).fadeIn("slow");
});
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
}
.step {
  display: none;
}
.errorMsg {
  display: none;
  color: red;
}
.error .errorMsg {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
  <div id="step1" class="step">
    <h1>Step 1</h1>
    <label>
      <span>Name :</span>
      <input name="name" />
      <div class="errorMsg">You must enter your name</div>
    </label>
    <label>
      <span>last name:</span>
      <input name="last_name" />
      <div class="errorMsg">You must enter your last name</div>
    </label>
    <!-- &&& -->
    <a href="#" onclick="show_step('2')">next</a>
  </div>
  <div id="step2" class="step">
    <h1>Step 2</h1>
    <label>
      <span>Email :</span>
      <input name="email" />
      <div class="errorMsg">You must enter your email</div>
    </label>
    <!-- &&& -->
    <a href="#" onclick="show_step('1')">back</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="show_step('3')">next</a>
  </div>
  <div id="step3" class="step">
    <h1>Step 3</h1>
    <a href="#" onclick="show_step('2')">back</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="show_step('4')">next</a>
  </div>
  <div id="step4" class="step">
    <h1>Step 4</h1>
    <a href="#" onclick="show_step('3')">back</a>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Update

OP Objective is to make the process independent of simple number indexing (although there is a counter but it's for the `url` variable). **Demo 2** relies on the `.next()` and `.prev()` methods to move, has an Object Literal to store it's data, and heavily relying on `this` to orient position and status during runtime. **Demo 2** has more *"moving parts"* thus harder for the user to manipulate through the console.

---

Use the **[`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** method to delegate the click event on all of the `<a>`nchors.

### Demo 1

```js
let currentStep = 0; // Variable that indicates the current step

$('#step' + currentStep).fadeIn("slow");

$('a.next, a.back').on('click', function(e) {
  var step = $(this).data('idx');
  xStep(step);
});

function xStep(step) {
  var data = $("#form").serialize();
  var url = 'saveTemp.php?step=' + step;
  var valid = true;

  // [OPTIONAL] We validate only if it is going forward
  if (currentStep < step) {

    // We search all input fields within the current step.  
    $('#step' + currentStep + ' .data').each(function(idx, el) {

      // If the field is empty
      if (!$(this).val()) {
        $(this).next('.msg').addClass('error');

        valid = false;

      } else {
        $(this).next('.msg').removeClass('error');

      }
    });
    if (!valid) {
      return
    }
  }

  $('#step' + currentStep).css("display", "none");
  $('#step' + step).fadeIn("slow");
  currentStep = step;
}
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
}

.step,
.msg {
  display: none;
}

.msg.error {
  display: inline-block;
  color: red;
}

legend {
  font: 600 3ch/1.2 Consolas
}

.dir {
  font-size: 2.5ch;
  text-decoration:none; 
}

.next::after {
  content: '\0a\25b6';
  font-size: 2ex;
}

.back::before {
  content: '\25c0\0a';
  font-size: 2ex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
  <fieldset id="step0" class="step">
    <legend>Step 1</legend>
    <label>
      First Name:
      <input name="fName" class='data'>
      <b class="msg">You must enter your name</b>
    </label>
    <label>
      Last Name:
      <input name="lName" class='data'>
      <b class="msg">You must enter your last name</b>
    </label>
    <!-- &&& -->
    <a href="#/" class='next dir' data-idx='1'>next</a>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset id="step1" class="step">
    <legend>Step 2</legend>
    <label>
      Email:
      <input name="email" type='email' class='data'>
      <b class="msg">You must enter your email</b>
    </label>
    <!-- &&& -->
    <a href="#/" class='back dir' data-idx='0'>back</a>
    <a href="#/" class='next dir' data-idx='2'>next</a>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset id="step2" class="step">
    <legend>Step 3</legend>
    <a href="#/" class='back dir' data-idx='1'>back</a>
    <a href="#/" class='next dir' data-idx='3'>next</a>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset id="step3" class="step">
    <legend>Step 4</legend>
    <input type='submit'>
    <a href="#/" class='back dir' data-idx='2'>back</a>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

---

**Details commented in Demo**

### Demo 2

```js
// Object literal stores data
var move = {
  step: 0,
  next: true
};
// Initial step
$('.step:first').fadeIn("slow");

// A click event on any a.dir...
$('a.dir').on('click', function(e) {

  /* Get the fieldset.step parent of this a.dir
  || if this a.dir has .back class...
  */
  var $current = $(this).parent('.step');
  if ($(this).hasClass('back')) {
    //...set the move object properties accordingly
    move.step -= 1;
    move.next = false;
  } else {
    //...otherwise change the properties the other way
    move.step += 1;
    move.next = true;
  }
  /* Invoke call() function on xStep() function
  || to set 'this' as the clicked <a>nchor
  */
  xStep.call(this, move, $current);
});

// Pass the move object and the current .step
function xStep(move, $current) {
  var data = $("#form").serialize();
  var url = 'saveTemp.php?step=' + move.step;

  // if next property is true...
  if (move.next) {

    /* find all .data in current .step and do
    || the following on each of them:
    */
    $current.find('.data').each(function(idx, el) {
      // Find input.data proceeding b.msg
      var $msg = $(this).next('.msg');

      // if this input.data has no value...
      if (!$(this).val()) {

        //...display error meassage
        $msg.addClass('error');
      } else {
        //...otherwise remove any error message
        $msg.removeClass('error');
      }
    });
    // if there are any b.msg.error, end the function
    if ($('.error').length > 0) {
      return;
    }
    // Remove current .step
    $current.css("display", "none");
    // fadeIn proceeding .step
    $current.next('.step').fadeIn("slow");
  } else {
    //...otherwise remove current .step 
    $current.css("display", "none");
    // fadeIn preceeding .step
    $current.prev('.step').fadeIn("slow");
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  font: 400 1.5ch/1.2 Consolas;
  font-variant: small-caps
}

label,
input {
  font: inherit;
  font-variant: normal
}

label {
  display: block;
}

.step,
.msg {
  display: none;
}

.msg.error {
  display: inline-block;
  color: red;
}

legend {
  font-size: 2.5ch;
}

.dir {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-top: 12px;
}

.next::after {
  content: '\0a\25b6';
  font-size: 2ex;
}

.back::before {
  content: '\25c0\0a';
  font-size: 2ex;
}

[type=submit] {
  float: right
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <fieldset class="step">
    <legend>Step 1</legend>
    <label>
      First Name:
      <input name="fName" class='data'>
      <b class="msg">First name is required</b>
    </label>
    <label>
      Last Name:&nbsp;
      <input name="lName" class='data'>
      <b class="msg">Last name is required</b>
    </label>
    <!-- &&& -->
    <a href="#/" class='next dir'>Next</a>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="step">
    <legend>Step 2</legend>
    <label>
      Email:
      <input name="email" class='data'>
      <b class="msg">Email: username@domain.com</b>
    </label>
    <!-- &&& -->
    <a href="#/" class='back dir'>Back</a>
    <a href="#/" class='next dir'>Next</a>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="step">
    <legend>Step 3</legend>
    <a href="#/" class='back dir'>Back</a>
    <a href="#/" class='next dir'>Next</a>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="step">
    <legend>Step 4</legend>
    <a href="#/" class='back dir'>Back</a>
    <input type='submit'>
  </fieldset>
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Friend my idea of removing those javascript attributes was  to avoid that those values were modified when editing them through the browser console, for example if I'm in step 1 (`onclick = "show_step ('1')"`), and change the values to step 4 (`onclick = "show_step ('4')"`), by clicking on continue this jumps to step 4, without respecting its order of steps.

Comment: Sadly the same happens with the new attributes that you have added :( `data-idx=''` it is not possible to continue the steps or to go back the steps to the back performing it in the following way: `<a href="#back" class="btn btn-warning back">back</a> <a href="#next" class="btn btn-success next">next</a>` without having to add those attributes that is easy to deceive?

Comment: @So12 I believe, to speak plainly, you are trying to prevent a user from advancing a step by using the console and undermining the whole procedure?

Comment: Yes exactly what you are saying

Comment: Your function `showStep()` relies on passing an index number, that is how your steps can be exploited and steps are skipped should the user manipulate through console because each step has a corresponding #id number. My demo doesn't have any #id numbers nor does the function `xStep()` need to pass an index number, but it does change a number variable called `step` which is passed onto you php. That number should be used with your AJAX/PHP. Let the demo I posted for you run without that `step` number. Basically `xStep()` replaces `showStep()`. Use the HTML in demo. Add only AJAX blocks to demo